# Checar existência de um elemento pelo atributo Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso basicamente checar se uma determinada div existe dentro de uma lista, a estrutura está assim:

```
<div class="content" id="divCheck">
   <div class="filho" value="1"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="2"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="3"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
   <div class="filho" value="1"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="2"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="3"></div>
</div>
```

Como posso verificar se na div com id `divCheck` existe um elemento com algum value, seria correto fazer um `each` nessa div ou da pra fazer isso com um simples `if` mesmo?

Comment: Esse seu codigo esta estranho, `<div>`sem fechamento das mesmas, e com values... É assim mesmo o código?

Comment: Esqueci de fechar, mas o código é só de exemplo para simplificar o entendimento da pergunta. Mas sim os values são necessários, talvez eu mude para o atributo "data-" no futuro.

Comment: Ah sim, mas o que você quer exatamente? verificar se existe um determinado elemento? Ou pegar todos os elementos dentro dela que possuem algum value?

Comment: Somente verificar se dentro de uma determinada div existe algum elemento com aquele Value, tal atributo nesse caso vai ser único daquele elemento dentro da div, e preciso manipular de forma diferente caso o mesmo já exista, se não devo adicionar um

Comment: Por que não utiliza `class`/`id` no lugar de `value`, já que não são campos de texto(input) e essa propriedade não será exibida para o usuário. Geralmente é feito assim quando se quer referenciar um elemento ou mesmo verificar se ele existe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa de loop. Você pode usar um seletor para achar se há ou não um elemento com um atributo e/ou um value:

```js
var existsValue1 = document.querySelector('#divCheck div[value="1"]');
console.log(!!existsValue1); //true

var existsValue8 = document.querySelector('#divCheck div[value="8"]');
console.log(!!existsValue8); //false
```

```html
<div class="content" id="divCheck">
   <div class="filho" value="1"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="2"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="3"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
   <div class="filho" value="1"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="2"></div>
   <div class="filho" value="3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigadão mano era isso mesmo que eu precisava.